# std::string displayed as <incomplete type> in the debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb

I want to debug my project using vscode,
but when i debug all std::string values are shown as **incomplete type**. in the launch.json i have:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Adapter CLI",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build-debug/cli/src/adapterCli",
            "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/cli/src/config.ini"],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable automatic structuring and indentation for gdb.",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }   
    ]
    
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? Can you rebuild without optimizations and retry?

Comment: In case of `clang` there could be a problem in displaying `std::string` due to lack of debug info, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41745527/72178.

Comment: i am using clang, what should i do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> what should i do to solve the problem?

Since you are using `clang` you have 2 options to solve "incomplete type" problem:

1. This is `clang` specific problem, so if you can use another compiler you can just use `gcc` instead of `clang`.
2. You can continue using `clang` but you will have to install debug info for `libstdc++` library. The exact way how to install it depends on the OS you are using. For Fedora/RedHat/CentOS use `sudo dnf debuginfo-install libstdc++-<some_version_here>.x86_64`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42031150/72178. For Ubuntu/Debian use `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-dbgsym`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65565897/72178.
3. You can also use `clang` with `-fno-limit-debug-info` option, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58527425/72178.